# BOPF Action oData Function XXX not found in the metadata?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I get the error
`Function XXX not found in the metadata !`
when i try to use `oDataV2Model.callFunction` the following way:

```
oDataModel.callFunction("/XXX", {
    methode: "POST",
    urlParameters: { Parameter1: "", Parameter2: "", Parameter3: new Date()  },
    success: function (oResultMod) {
        console.log(oResultMod);
    },
    error: function (oError) {
        console.log(oError);
    }
});
```

BOPF Configuration:
[image]

metadata:

```
<FunctionImport Name="XXX" ReturnType="ZZZ.DDD" m:HttpMethod="POST" sap:action-for="ZZZ.AAA">
<Parameter Name="Parameter1" Type="Edm.String" Mode="In" MaxLength="60"/>
<Parameter Name="Parameter2" Type="Edm.String" Mode="In" MaxLength="12"/>
<Parameter Name="Parameter3" Type="Edm.DateTime" Mode="In" Precision="0"/>
</FunctionImport>
```

If I try the same in gateWay Client it works:
[image: It works!]

The Model is set via Manifest:

```
"dataSources": {
    "odataSource": {
        "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZUPD_C_UPDATES_CDS/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "odataVersion": "2.0"
        }
    }           
},
...
"models": {
    "oDataModel": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
        "settings": {
            "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
            "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay",
            "defaultCountMode": "Request",
            "useBatch" : false
        },
        "dataSource": "odataSource"
    }
},
```

UI5 Version: 1.71.40

There are no spelling mistakes, and between it working in gateway client und all other operations on the oDataModel working (read, write, update) I do not know where to look next.

Has anyone an idea what I can try to find the error?
thanks in advance!

Edit:
Mafinfest + BOPF Config
I tried the same via SEGW instead of BOPF and CDS and it worked. Via BOPF and CDS only the SAPUI5 Framework has a Problem, if send the request any other way it works (GateWay Client, Rest Client extention for VS Code).

Comment: Is the metadata snippet actually from the browser network tab? If not, could you share what the browser really receives upon the `$metadata` request in the devtool's network tab?

Comment: Are you creating more than one `ODataModel`s with the same service URL? E.g. one via `manifest.json` and one from a controller code manually..

Comment: Caching might be a problem.

Comment: Caching is not the problem, checked for that one,. The Metadata sniplet is directly from the network tab and in create the Model via Manifest, not inside the controllers, i will update the question with manifest sniplet

Comment: Sometimes these need to be called as `ZZZ.AAA`

Comment: ZZZ is the Name of the oDataService and AAA the EntityType of the EntitySet that corresponds to the Parameters of the FunctionCall. Would I need to do "/oDataService/Entitytype/FunctionCall" or "/oDataService/EntitySet/FunctionCall" or do I need the Name of the oData Service at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the e marked below was wrong,...

```
oDataModel.callFunction("/XXX", {
    method!!!e!!! : "POST",
    urlParameters: { Parameter1: "", Parameter2: "", Parameter3: new Date()  },
    success: function (oResultMod) {
        console.log(oResultMod);
    },
    error: function (oError) {
        console.log(oError);
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess TypeScript would've helped identifying the typo earlier

Comment: very true, normally i do use TS for my apps but this is for my first Launchpad Plugin and I didnt want to mess with the generated project (easy-ui5 flp-plugin) before understand what i am doing